# Supremum of Continuous Functions (Least Upper Bound)

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

I'm trying to work out a question of a past exam, but I can't seem to figure it out.  If I could get some help, I would be very appreciative.  The question is:

Prove the following statement or provide a counter example, including an explanation of why it's a counterexample: If $f_n(x)$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$ for each $n=1,2,\dots,$ and $0\leq f_n(x)\leq 1,$ for every $n\in N$ and every $x\in[0,1]$, then $f(x)=\sup_{n\in N} f_n(x)$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement is not true. Take the following functions as a counterexample:

$$f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & 0≤x<\frac 12 -\frac {1}{n+1} \\
\frac{n+1}{2}x-\frac{n-1}{4} & \frac 12 -\frac {1}{n+1}≤x<\frac12+\frac{1}{n+1} \\
1 & \frac 12 -\frac {1}{n+1}≤x≤1
\end{cases}
$$

Then

$$f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
x & 0≤x<\frac 12 \\
\frac 12 & x=\frac12 \\
1 & \frac 12 <x≤1
\end{cases}
$$

which is clearly not continuous at $x=\frac 12$